# How to parse all nodes of given XML to an array in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

How to parse all nodes of following XML to an array in python

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CARLIST> 
  <CAR> 
    <MODEL>BENZ</MODEL>  
    <SPECIFICATIONS> 
      <ENGINE>TURBO</ENGINE>  
      <FUELTYPE>PETROL</FUELTYPE> 
    </SPECIFICATIONS> 
  </CAR>  
  <CAR> 
    <MODEL>FIAT</MODEL>  
    <SPECIFICATIONS> 
      <ENGINE>DIESEL</ENGINE>  
      <FUELTYPE>PETROL</FUELTYPE> 
    </SPECIFICATIONS> 
  </CAR> 
</CARLIST>
```

Comment: What kind of xml is this ? Also show your attempt and ask specific question.

Comment: Given that sample XML as input, how the output array should look like? Also post your attempted code so far and explain what's the problem with it

Answer (score 0):

> [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) is a Python module that makes working with XML feel like you
>   are working with JSON

**Example:**

```
s = """<?xml ... </CARLIST>"""
parsed = xmltodict.parse(s)
for car in parsed['CARLIST']['CAR']:
  print(dict(car))

{u'SPECIFICATIONS': OrderedDict([(u'ENGINE', u'TURBO'), (u'FUELTYPE', u'PETROL')]), u'MODEL': u'BENZ'}
{u'SPECIFICATIONS': OrderedDict([(u'ENGINE', u'DIESEL'), (u'FUELTYPE', u'PETROL')]), u'MODEL': u'FIAT'}
```